# Text box not added to all UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  }

    // Configure the cell...
 if(indexPath.row < 8)
 {
  CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 31);
  UITextField *myfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textRect];
  myfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
  myfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
  myfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
  myfield.minimumFontSize = 2.0;

  myfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
  myfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
  myfield.autocorrectionType= UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
  myfield.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
  myfield.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

  [self.  addSubview:myfield];
 }


    return cell;

}
```

I wrote the above code for displaying textboxes in UITableViewCell (up to eight cells ) but the text box is displaying in the first cell only is there anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: This is the third question from you with the title *"iphone programming"*. Please use a descriptive title, like *"Text not displaying in UITableView text box"*.

Comment: @DarkDust: Actually, his fifth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[self.addSubview:myfield];
```

Change this to:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: myfield];
[myfield release];
```

---

However, I agree with [Björn Marschollek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459812/bjorn-marschollek) about design, so here is how this method should look:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifierWithTextBox = @"CellWithTextBox";
 static NSString *CellIdentifierOther = @"CellOther";

 UITableViewCell *cell;
 if(indexPath.row < 8)
 {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierWithTextBox];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierWithTextBox] autorelease];
      CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 31);
      UITextField *myfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textRect];
      myfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
      myfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
      myfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
      myfield.minimumFontSize = 2.0;

      myfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
      myfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
      myfield.autocorrectionType= UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
      myfield.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
      myfield.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

     [cell.contentView addSubview: myfield];
     [myfield release];
   }
 }
 else
 {
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierOther];
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierOther] autorelease];
     }
 }
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to release `myfield` afterwards or it is going to leak. Anyway, you should add the subview only when you alloc a new cell instance instead of adding it every time a cell is being drawn. Otherwise you are going to have several fields on top of another. You may want to add a text field to every cell and only hide it if you do not need it.

Comment: i tried this one but it wont make any difference it just displays in first cell of the tableview

Comment: @Björn Marschollek, I agree.  I have updated my answer.  @user564963, sorry to hear you are still having problems.  Try cutting and pasting the above method into your code and see if there is an improvement.  If not, I think the problem may lie elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @user564963: Are you returning 1 in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method? If so, change it to the right amount of cells you want to display.